# How to declare a superclass when writing a Java file in Android Studio

Tags: java, class

When I made a Java class in Android Studio, it did not display an option for declaring a superclass, and I could not find any help on this website or others for declaring a superclass in my code or when writing the file. Can I please have a code as an answer or some pictures? Much appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Do some research on the actual language? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: This is off-topic. Not programming related. Please take a look at IntelliJ Idea (that Studio is based on) help site on how to use its New Class wizard. And, if you also don't know about the `extends SuperClass` keyword, please start with Java not Android. With inner classes and what not, it will be too hard to make good progress there.

Comment: @engineercoding nonsense comment I would say

Comment: @RaviThapliyal why it would not make sense here once is related with development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do such a thing with Android Studio, so you better create your class via "New > Class" and then write "extend < SuperClassName>" as always ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can create your custom template for creating a subclass by going to `file->settings->editor->file and code template`. press `create template(insert)` (the green + button) and set the name to SubClass or whatever you want and insert this for the template

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} extends ${SUPERCLASS} {
}
```

now when you create new java class you will find SubClass on the kinds available.

Answer (score -1):

just write extends AppCompatActivity after your class name

```
public class MainCourseActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
...
...
}
```